# How would I recreate this horizontal line in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've seen variations of this idea... in HTML, the `<hr />` tag creates a horizontal line that can be used as a spacing tool to separate headings, blocks of content, etc... I'd like to create such a line using Photoshop and have it look like this...

[image]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

How would I do this in Photoshop? Are there tutorials dedicated to this?

Comment: Have a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/photoshop-curved-shadow/1470#1470 for answers to a similar question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use Marquee tool to create a line.

   [image: Step 1: Line]
2. Use Marquee tool to create a section above the line and fill the selection with a gradient.

   [image: Step 2: Gradient]
3. Mask the layer with a vertically-reflected gradient (Opaque at the middle, transparent at the edges)

   [image: Step 3: Isolated layer mask]
4. Done!

   [image: Complete]

Comment: In Photoshop, one might change step 2 above to: apply a layer style using gradient or drop shadow." This would make later fiddling and adjustment easier.