# How to create this fading shadow effect in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to know how to create this shadow effect in photoshop. I know how to make shadow  in photoshop but don't know how to make this fading shadow on the left and right side in the image.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photoshop curved Shadow ](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/photoshop-curved-shadow)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I recreate this horizontal line in Photoshop?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/how-would-i-recreate-this-horizontal-line-in-photoshop)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no automated way to do this easily. You need to manually create the shadows.
[image: quick tut on arched shadows]

Answer (score 2):

One very quick and easy solution would be to ...

Select the brush tool with the hardness value set to zero percent.
Click once on an empty layer to get a feathered dot as shown below.

[image]

Now, press "ctrl+t" to transform the dot into the desired shape.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Put a shape over the shadow and reduce its opacity to get the result below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One quick way, would be to create a shape behind it, and end each side on a bit of a curve.

Next, add your shadow to this shape, and place it in a layer below, nudging it into place.