# client logo - large dropshadow and awkward angle - looks terrible on any media, any guidance?

Tags: logo, composition, white-space

I am reluctant to post the actual logo for risk of repercussions, but I have taken away any identifiable features, leaving the "problem" parts. Here is the logo on a white background:

[image]

It looks awful when dropped on to a white background, and makes designing any kind of media hard work due to the angle as it just doesn't "sit" right on the document. I feel the focus point is the "box" rather than the actual logo within.

I am not a designer by trade.

Are there any tips for working with something like this? I appreciate it's a vague question but it's quite frustrating not knowing how to make it look good with other media!

Comment: There are quite a few questions on making nicer shadows, if that's what you are looking for. e.g. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/how-to-create-this-fading-shadow-effect-in-photoshop

Comment: I will take a look - I am unsure how much editing I can get away with as they are quite keen on the logo as it is, (typically). Thanks for the link

Comment: If you can simply drop the shadow darkness down to 10% it would help a great deal. Does the logo fill that entire box?

Comment: the bulk of the logo is text, with one of the corners being a triangle of solid colour. It sort of looks like a "shipping label" for lack of a better description.

Comment: Is removing the white background not an option?

Comment: +1 and for more on the general problem, see the excellently titled earlier question [designing around an awful logo](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/785/designing-around-an-awful-logo)

Answer (score 3):

If removing the rotation is not feasible (or allowed). I think I would try to get away with reducing the darkness of the shadow. A less intense shadow will do a great deal to "lighten" the footprint overall.

[image: shadow]

Much less eye-catching in my opinion and less dominant in any layout. All i did was drop it to 10%.

Answer (score 2):

Just put it on a dark background. Also realize as soon as you flatten it to send to a printer the drop shadow is going to get a lot more subtle.