# How to I create these lines with shadows?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've been trying to create these lines as seen in this picture here but with no luck:

[image]

I have found a few posts that are similar like this: [How to create this fading shadow effect in photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/how-to-create-this-fading-shadow-effect-in-photoshop), and I've tried to follow the answers but this design asks for a very subtle white shadow which I can't seem to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I think those are just drop shadows with different size/distance: the 'lower' a layer is in the 'space', the less distance and size its shadow has.

[image]

[image]