# What is this horizontal shadow effect called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tutorial

Ok, so this is a bit embarrassing: But I cannot for the life of me find instructions that show me how to achieve this type of effect in Photoshop.

If anyone knows what it is called or how it can be done, I would be most grateful.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ1d2.png]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photoshop curved Shadow](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/photoshop-curved-shadow)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"photoshop paper shadow" gives plenty results on this specific effect.

Answer (score 0):

Simply...

1. Create a rectangle the size you want matching your canvas or background color.
2. Under that layer create an oval shape (Ellipse tool) just slightly narrower than the rectangle you just created but with a darker color, typically black.
3. This step you will need to play with until it looks right - with the oval layer selected under Filter click "Convert for Smart Layer." This way you can add a blur without converting the shape to a raster image. Add a Blur / Gradient Blur (will need to adjust this to your needs) and then change the opacity to something very light, possibly 35-50%.

TIPS - nudging the oval shape layer up helps to get create that 'tight' shadow with sharp edges on each end. Don't forget to align the rectangle and the oval before or after just to make sure both appear centered.

Answer (score -1):

Its called page divider , You can google using this keyword.

Comment: While that may be a broader term for it, I don't think that answers Anders' question since it's a little _too_ broad.