# Simple Line Fading Away At Both Ends

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I am not much of a designer. Looks like a very basic thing to do but i don't know how to do it. I just want to create a line that is blurred from the ends and have this shade at the bottom of it. Its a kind of a separator that i can use on a website. I want to do it in Photoshop. As an example, check out the following image:

[image]

Comment: In Photoshop I would probably draw an ellipse and use gaussian blur ( you could use smart filters to keep it editable ) and then make a rectangle selection and mask out the top part of it. The line at the top is just a matter of duplicating the ellipse layer and masking out the bottom part so that you are left with a line at the top.

Comment: Very Similar: [Photoshop curved Shadow](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1441/8708)

Comment: A good way to make the line portion of this is to draw a line, add a layer mask, and then use the Gradient tool (Reflected gradient), check 'reversed' and draw it on the layer mask. (Your selected colors should be black and white)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a New Layer and  then Using **Rectangular Marquee Tool** Draw line and then choose brush tool to paint

[image]

[image]

Using Eraser tool erase the both ends and set the Eraser Opacity to 50%

Make a new layer and using Rectangular Marquee Tool draw rectangle below the edge line and paint gently using brush which set to opacity 50%.

[image]

Now choose the line layer and select Gaussian Blur and set radius to 20. See the final result below. Hope it helps You !!!

[image]

Comment: While you were able to reproduce the proposed picture, I would like to add that using the eraser is not always very precise (and I haven't used it in 10 years myself). Changing the transparency later is just a lot easier with layer styles.

Comment: @KMSTR  - You mean not to use the eraser tool at the edges?

Comment: Yes. The fading out edges can be done in non-destructive layer styles. While erasing is a destructive workflow. Meaning you can't tweak it later.

Comment: @KMSTR - I agree to your suggestion, but it is the simplest way to achieve the design and also OP is not much of a designer.

Comment: I agree it is the simplest way. But if you ever change your mind (or the client does), you have to do it over and over again. So why not learn it how to do it properly from the start?

Comment: @Bala I am unable to achieve this effect. Using the eraser cannot be as accurate who is not much of a photoshop user. Is there any other way i do it ?

Comment: @Bala can you update your answer with the psd file if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make a rectangular shape of the total size of your line (e.g. 1px by 600px). Set fill to 0%. Double click the layer to access the layer styles. Add gradient overlay. Edit gradient to go from 0% black to 50% black to 90% black.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Settings -Variable width profile]

I'm doing a straight line (in Illustrator) with faded edges and I just selected a Variable width profile setting next to the stroke setting 
(Not sure if this would be relevant for a curved line or shape though)

Photoshop is a lot easier - I add a layer mask and apply gradients to the edges
I would practically never use the eraser tool as it's a destructive edit.
If you use layer masks you can always change it later